# Exception when storing large BasicDBObject to mongodb with java

Tags: java, mongodb, object, store, nosql

I want to store large objects in mongoDB but I'm getting errors when persisting huge objects (byte[] may be > 5MB). Is it possible to store the data that way? I'm always getting an exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object too big: 4821537" when calling "insert" on DB...

**Snippet:**

```
private byte[] persistObject(String id, byte[] value){

    BasicDBObject doc = new BasicDBObject();
    doc.append("id", id);
    doc.append("value", value); // may be really huge! > 5MB of size

    try {
        getObjectCollection().save(doc);
    } catch (MongoException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return value;
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object too big: 4821537
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:217)
at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:180)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:72)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:537)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:517)
```

Thanks for your help/tips :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your mongodb version is 1.6。BSON objects in MongoDB are limited in size(4MB)。Pls upgrade the mongodb version to 1.7+ . 16MB in v1.7/1.8, higher limits in the future。

Comment: My Version is **db version v1.6.5** as this is the production release. I'm not sure if I should use an unstable development build in my project... Is there any other good no-sql db with a java interface that you would recommend?

Comment: I see mongodb's jira。1.8 rc2 is release。It haven't critical bugs。 You can try now。Other suggestions are membase and redis 。They are stable and have good performance。

Comment: I tried the version of mongodb you mentioned. It works! But you have to use the latest java-driver (version 2.5) to store large objects. Version 2.4 doesnt store them and throws exceptions too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's alright~。The latest java-driver has supported the new Mongo 1.8 features, like advanced post-processing on results (replace, merge, reduce, inline).Good News!~

Comment: What are the object (bson) limits for 1.8? Where to find them? Why do the object (bson) limits exist?

Comment: Found an explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667597/understanding-mongodb-bson-document-size-limit