# Why does MongoDB have collections

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB being document-oriented, the structure of collections seems to be a special case of documents. By that I mean one can define a document to contain other documents. So a collection is just a document containing other documents.

So why do we need collections after all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Logically yes, you could design a database system like that, but practically speaking no.

- A collection has indexes on the documents in it.
- A collection requires the documents in it to have unique ids.
- A document is limited in size.

Comment: Thanks. What is the document size limit?

Comment: @randomBlue document size: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667597/understanding-mongodb-bson-document-size-limit

Comment: Perhaps better to refer to the source: 16MB currently: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Documents

Answer (score 1):

- Object ids (`_id` top-level document attribute) must be unique *within* a collection. Multiple collections may have the same _id, just like in RDBMs where the key constraint is per-table, yet multiple tables may contain the same value for a key.

Answer (score 0):

collections is a container for documents. so when you say a document that contain other documents that s kinda wrong because, already, a document can have inner documents.

Collection is the unit where you put together the documents. Be aware that due to schema free design, you can put anything in a collection but it s not a good design. so collection is kinda logical container for documents. same as tables in relational world.