# Limit amount of text submitted in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, textarea, meteor-helper

I have a simple Meteor app, that lets users fill in a form into a `<textarea>` which will be displayed on their public profile.

Everything is working, I happen to be using `{{#markdown}}` to display the text on public profile. Everything works well.

> **Questions:**

- How would I limit the amount of text the user can submit **?**
- Does Meteor somehow limit this **?**
- Is it a good idea to put a limit on this **?**

I assume some code would have to be put in a `server js` file rather than `client js` side

No user would need more than a page or two of text.

I know I this will allow only 5K of text in box...

`<textarea maxlength="50000">`

- but I think that can be defeated in the browser

~ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You are correct in that maxlength will limit browser side. You can also use the `.length` property of a string server-side to ensure it stays below the character limit you set.
2. You are only hard-limited by the maximum document size in [MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667597/understanding-mongodb-bson-document-size-limit), which is 16MB.
3. Absolutely.  Having a collections of really large strings of text is going to affect performance.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I noticed this on http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_textarea_maxlength
(allthe more reason to do server side)
**Note:** The maxlength attribute of the textarea tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions, or in Opera 12 and earlier versions.