# MongoDB - MongoError: Resulting document after update is larger than 16777216

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this error in my ExpressJS app:

```
Error updating stream: MongoError: Resulting document after update is larger than 16777216
_http_server.js:192
    throw new RangeError(`Invalid status code: ${statusCode}`);
```

So I assume that my document has exceeded the limit.

How can I increase the limit?

I got this [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/) from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667597/understanding-mongodb-bson-document-size-limit). But how do I use it in my app? How do I start?

I am using mongoose to store and retrieve my data.

Any ideas/ hints?

This is my document schema in mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');

// Declare schema
var streadatamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    data: {
        type: Object
    },
    entries_number: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    last_entry_at: {
        type: Date
    },
    created_at: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        index: 1 // Note 1
    },
});

streamSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);

// Export schema
// Model.paginate()
mongoose.model("Stream", streamSchema);
```

I reckon it is the `data` field has too much data in it now.

Answer (score 9):

> So I assume that my document has exceeded the limit.
>
> How can I increase the limit?

The size limit in Mongo is [hardcoded in the source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/4211c6a8de32fa774b1c28fb82a96f965fd550b7/src/mongo/bson/util/builder.h#L50):

```
/* Note the limit here is rather arbitrary and is simply a standard. generally the code works
   with any object that fits in ram.
   Also note that the server has some basic checks to enforce this limit but those checks are not exhaustive
   for example need to check for size too big after
     update $push (append) operation
     various db.eval() type operations
*/
const int BSONObjMaxUserSize = 16 * 1024 * 1024;

/*
   Sometimes we need objects slightly larger - an object in the replication local.oplog
   is slightly larger than a user object for example.
*/
const int BSONObjMaxInternalSize = BSONObjMaxUserSize + ( 16 * 1024 );

const int BufferMaxSize = 64 * 1024 * 1024;
```

The only way to change it is by changing the source code and building your own version of Mongo from the source.

Comment: @rsp how do I build my own version of Mongo from the source?

Comment: Is this resolved or still we need to build mongo from the source ?

Comment: 2023 and it's still an issue :'(