# MongoDB has aggregation size limit as it allows only 16MB

Tags: mongodb

As we all know that the MongoDB has aggregation size limit as it allows only 16MB in a single document. Is this issue fixed in the latest MongoDB version. Have anybody tried that?

Comment: Here is some info about [Aggregation Pipeline Limits](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/index.html).

Comment: Can you try this `allowDiskUse(true);` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding MongoDB BSON Document size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667597/understanding-mongodb-bson-document-size-limit)

Comment: Use GridFS for storing large amount of data